# Pooled Variance from two Variables' SD, but no correlation?

Tags: variance, pooling

Is there any way to calculate a pooled variance in a within subjects design when I have the SDs and sample size, but no correlation between X and Y?

I'm trying to calculate an effect size using single sample t tests, using the difference of Variable X minus Variable Y (and my null hypothesis is that there is no difference) and the original author of a study provides means and SD, but NOT the correlation of X,Y. I know the formula for pooling these SDs using the correlation or covariance of X,Y but the authors didn't supply that information.

Comment: What equation do you mean when there is correlation? I think you’ve mixed up two notions.

Comment: @Dave My reading of the question is that the sample means and standard deviations are known pre-treatment and are known post-treatment, but the correlation between pre- and post-treatment is not known.  That would suggest that the standard deviation of paired differences is not known (though its range is bounded).  I may be wrong in this reading

Comment: @Henry I think it’s the usual pooled variance formula with the OP thinking something about the variance of a sum of random variables, but I could be wrong with my read, too.

Comment: @Dave.  I would have thought a "pooled variance" was not suitable for a paired $t$-test, where you need to use the variance of the paired differences.  If $x=(1,2,3,4,5,6)$ you could draw a different conclusion $y = (2,3,4,5,6,7)$ compared to $y=(7,6,5,4,3,2)$ in a paired test but not in an unpaired test

Comment: Sorry if there is a lack of clarity - originally I was creating single sample t tests and transforming them into effect size r, then realized there was no need for the t tests if I use Cohen's d instead of r so I'm using this route instead. I still need a standard deviation of the difference scores. I'm taking the difference between variable X and Y, and dividing it by the standard deviation of the difference, but some of the authors do not report the SD of the difference and I get stuck at that stage. Henry is correct about the paired differences, and I wondered if there was any other way.